# possible to debug/pry from methadone's App class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, aruba

I started a blank project with [methadone](https://github.com/davetron5000/methadone), an awesome framework for building command line apps. The only problem is that I am unable to debug from within the `App` class that's in `bin/my_app`

The `App` class is a file created when you run methadone. Here's how I'm trying to use pry

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'optparse'
require 'methadone'
require 'my_app'
require 'pry'

class App
  include Methadone::Main
  include Methadone::CLILogging

  main do
     binding.pry    #  <= pry here
  end

  ...
```

When I run `rake features` I can tell the running process is trying to do something with pry since it pauses for a few seconds. I get the following error and then rake/cucumber is aborted.

```
process still alive after 3 seconds (ChildProcess::TimeoutError)
```

I can use pry just fine from the cucumber steps, rspec, or any other place, just not from anywhere in this `App` class.

One very interesting thing is that if I run my command line app from the console it WILL stop where pry is. It just wont pop into pry when using cucumber.

**How can I get the app to work with pry when I'm running `rake features`?**

### Update

Sorry, I should clarify that methadone comes with aruba. So my cucumber scenario would look like this

```
When I successfully run `my_app arg1`
```

However, it WILL go into debug/pry if I run it with

```
bundle exec bin/my_app
```

Comment: It sounds like whatever you're using to test it is invoking the binary explicitly, but hooking up a stream to the standard input of the process running the app. Without knowing more about how you're testing (aruba? greenletters? rolling your own?), we can only really make guesses.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek Sorry, updated the question - I'm using aruba and show the exact cucumber/aruba step I'm using. I don't think it's a problem with aruba though since I can pry it. I know that methadone purposely hides errors from users so I believe it's something to do with that.

Comment: are you sure it's `I successfully run the command...` and not `I successfully run...`? I can only find the former ([link](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/blob/f16b12e4031cdff7f6b16031b7d17ec5582576a0/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb#L65)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pry-remote](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote) to connect to a pry session in the Aruba-managed subprocess.

(Disclosure: I paired with @Dty to come to this solution)

Comment: Just remember to set the aruba timeout to longer than 3 seconds so you have time to launch pry-remote

Answer (score 1):

Aruba runs the app in a totally separate process, so I would guess what's happening is that when aruba runs your app, pry starts up at a prompt and waits for input.  Since it doesn't get any, aruba times out after three seconds (the default it will wait for an app to complete).  This is why you see the "process still alive" issue.

I'm not 100% sure how you could get the standard input of your shell that's running `rake features` to connect to your app's standard input so you could issue pry commands, but I don't think aruba was designed to allow this.

You have a couple of options:

- Tag your scenario with @announce, and use `When I run interactively...` followed by several `When I type` - these commands *should* go to the interactive pry console that's waiting.  Kind of kludgy, but it might work
- Execute a unit test of your `App` class.  You'll need to replace the call to `go!` with something like `go! if $0 == __FILE__` so that you can `require` your executable in a test and manipulate `App` directly.

I have not tried either of these, but the second option feels a bit better and could also be improved with support from the library, if you can figure out a good way to do this.

Comment: Well, I CAN pry into any aruba steps even when run with `rake features` so that's why I was thinking it was something with methadone.

Comment: Yeah, cause those are in the process run from your shell, so the stdin/stdout are all connected.  If you end up implementing option #2 and Methadone could add features/hooks to help, please file an issue and I'll look into it